# rsync process running on BeagleBone Black after boot from microSD

Tags: rsync, boot, beagleboneblack

Please could someone explain what is happening on BBB during boot process from SD card and why there is each time long running rsync process? Does BBB automatically flash internal eMMC? I'm using official Debian image from their webpage.

Output from ps aux | grep ...

```
rsync -aAXv /boot/uboot/ /tmp/boot/ --exclude=MLO --exclude=u-boot.img --exclude=*bak --exclude=flash-eMMC.txt --exclude=flash-eMMC.log
```

then later another rsync:

```
rsync -aAXv /bin /boot /dev /etc /home /lib /lost+found /media /mnt /opt /proc /root /run /sbin /selinux /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var /tmp/rootfs/ --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/run/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/boot/* --exclude=/lib/modules/*
```

output from top:

```
 2566 root      20   0 29840 3064  620 R  23,0  0,6   1:12.21 rsync                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 2564 root      20   0 21604 9424  868 S  20,5  1,9   1:02.67 rsync                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   72 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   2,5  0,0   0:10.37 mmcqd/0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   75 root      20   0     0    0    0 D   2,2  0,0   0:42.00 mmcqd/1
```

output from mount:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot/uboot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mmcblk1p2 on /tmp/rootfs type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
```

Thanks.

Comment: From my experience, it does flash eMMC every time, even without pressing `user boot button`. Despite what official documentation says, at least on Debian the images I was using, pressing `user boot button` was not required to flush eMMC.

Comment: So debian image contains boot scripts that each time flush eMMC... good to know thanks. I had experienced few shutdowns when i ran some CPU/RAM intensive job shortly after boot. Flush eMMC + my job probably exhausted RAM or cause overheating.

Answer (score 0):

From the website (http://beagleboard.org/latest-images)

```
BeagleBone (Runs on BeagleBone Black as well without flashing the eMMC)

    Debian (BeagleBone, BeagleBone Black - 2GB SD) 2014-05-14 - more info - bittorrent - md5: 35877ce21e8ed0eb1bdc6819ad71c317
    Angstrom Distribution (BeagleBone, BeagleBone Black - 4GB SD) 2013-06-20 - more info

BeagleBone Black (eMMC flasher)

    Debian (BeagleBone Black - 2GB eMMC) 2014-05-14 - more info - bittorrent - md5: 74615fb680af8f252c034d3807c9b4ae
    Angstrom Distribution (BeagleBone Black - 2GB eMMC) 2013-09-04 - more info - bittorrent
```

So sounds like the BeagleBone image will run on the BeagleBone black without flashing eMMC.